# create link to download file

Tags: files

I'm adapting a drupal module to my need. It permit to upload a pdf to insert it into a node add form in an iframe to display the file.
I've need also to insert a link to download the previous uploaded file.

I've read and try thousand of guide and documentation but nothing that work or adapt to my scope.

Is possible to find an easy way to create by code a download link?

Comment: Could you add some of your code to your question? It would be very helpful to figure out where to hook in exactly.

Comment: this is the main part, the $content will print into the nodd/add form
`$content = '<a href="'.$filelink.'">Download MB</a><br><br><iframe frameborder="0" width="800px" height="900px"  src="'.$path.'"><p>'.$file_text.'</p></iframe>';`
i need to create $filelink to start file download

Comment: Please add that code to the question, not in into a comment. So you are in a template? What template?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the [PDF Reader module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf_reader).

> PDF Reader will render your entity file fields with the selected PDF
>   renderer.
>
> The implemented PDF renderers are:
>
> - Google Docs Viewer
> - pdf.js - PDF Reader in JavaScript
> - Direct PDF embed
> - Microsoft Office Web Viewer(7.x-2.x-dev)

This module lets you specify any file field to render as a PDF embedded in a node. It also has an option to display download link for the embedded PDF.

Comment: No, this is not what i need. i want to display contentin the same page, with iframe and also insert a force download link

Answer (score -1):

You can use below HTML to download files:

```
$content = "<a href='FILE LINK' download='FILE NAME TO DOWNLOAD WITH EXTENSION'">Click here to download</a>';
```